# Как преобразовать постоянную ссылку по временную?

Tags: php

Всем привет) Не знаю, так ли сформулировал вопрос) В общем, в чём суть: отправили меня на практику и, как полагается, дали работать с тем, что ныне до этого я никогда не видывал и ещё столько же не видел бы. На практике дали такое задание: я должен сделать что-то вроде механизма обмена временными ссылками на PHP. У предприятия есть облачное хранилище, в него сотрудник предприятия загружает файл и далее копирует ссылку на него и вставляет в специальную строчку. Нажимает на кнопочку типа "Получить временную ссылку", получает её, копирует и отдаёт клиенту. Ссылка должна жить пару-тройку часов, а потом умирать. Самая главная проблема в том, что пользоваться базами данных или текстовыми файлами нельзя (не знаю по какой причине), а вот почти весь материал по временным ссылкам в интернете содержит БД или текстовики. Собственно, никакие облачные хранилища реализовывать не надо и механизм загрузки файлов на сервер уже как-то там реализован. Надо лишь скопировать постоянную ссылку на файл и преобразовать её во временную. Знание языка почти нулевое, времени разбираться с ним и учить тоже, к сожалению, нет... Если кто-то поможет, желательно как можно подробнее, буду сильно благодарен)

Comment: вероятно сохранять нужно или в сессию, или в куки.

Answer (score 1):

**Есть небольшая идея.**

Раз механизм существует и он спокойно отправляет файлы, то вы не думали что можно использовать простое название файла? Тоесть за уникальный токен взять имя файла. А пользователю посылать прямую ссылку на файл.

***(вам не прийдется где-то записывать что по такому токену предоставить такой файл)***

*"Надо лишь скопировать постоянную ссылку на файл и преобразовать её во временную. "* Ничего не надо. Делаете php скрипт который должен отработатся раз в час, он проверяет время создания файла и его сносит. (такие вещи делают cron, timers и тррр)(зависит от ос)

***(ведь он вам больше не понадобится, срок жизни файла истек)***

Comment: К сожалению, прямую ссылку на файл отправлять нельзя, она должна быть зашифрована, т.к. предприятие крупное (его и так недавно Петя атаковал:)) И вторая загвоздка в том, что основной сервер с облачным хранилищем не воспринимает php (только html), поэтому придётся именно копировать постоянную ссылку с одного сервака, а преобразовывать во временную на втором сервере.

Comment: Очень странное предприятие... :)

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку нельзя использовать БД или другие средства хранения информации, то всю инфу надо хранить в ссылке. Делаем так

1) создаем ключ шифрования - какой именно зависит от типа шифрования

2) создаем еще одну секретную строку для подписи

Далее для каждой ссылки

1) берем ссылку - это строка

2) шифруем ее секретным ключом. Получаем строку раз.

3) берем время в виде строки, до которого ссылка будет жить, и шифруем его. Получаем строку два.

4) обе строки объединяем, берем от них md5 (или sha1), потом добавляем секретную строку для подписи и снова берем md5

```
md5(секретная строка 2 . md5(шифрованная ссылка . шифрованное время))
```

Получаем строку - подпись.

Формируем временную ссылку на скрипт, главное в урл передать строку раз, строку два и подпись.

Пишем скрипт, который получает $_GET параметры - зашифрованную ссылку, зашифрованное время и подпись из п 4).

Сначала проверяем что подпись верная - если нет возвращаем ошибку.

Потом расшифровываем время и проверяем, что время не прошло.

И уже потом, если все ок, расшифровываем урл и пробрасываем данные файла через скрипт - как бы даем его на скачивание.

Если хочется попроще, то урл и время можно шифровать base64 и надеяться только на подпись md5. В этом случае секретная строка 1) не понадобится.